# Trouble linking an html form to a javascript function through jquery listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having some trouble using a jquery listener on a submit button to get it to run a function on the form's data.
I have this html form:

```
<div class = "window" id="patientsignup">
<h1>Add New Patient</h1>
<form id = "form1">
<label>First name: </label> <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="First"><br>
<label>Last name: </label><input type="text" name="LastName" value="Last"><br>
<label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" value="johndoe@email.com"><br>
<label>Phone Number: </label><input type="text" name="phonenumber" value="Phone Number"><br>
<input type="button" id="patientcreatebutton" name="createbutton" value="Create Patient">
</form>
</div>
```

And I'm using this jQuery listener in my CSS stylesheet:

```
$('#patientcreatebutton').click(
    createpatient($('#form1'));
);
```

Here's the javascript function it's calling.

```
function createpatient(form) {
console.log("Begin creating patient");
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var username= form.email.value;
var email= form.email.value;
var doctorIdentifier= currentUser.id;
randkey = makeid();
var password= randkey;
var doctorCode= randkey;
var phoneNumberForPatient= form.phonenumber.value; 
var doctorsUserName= currentUser.username;

Parse.Cloud.run("inviteUser", {"email": email,  "password": password, "doctorCode": password, "phoneNumberForPatient": phoneNumberForPatient, "doctorUserName": doctorsUserName, "doctorIdentifier": doctorIdentifier}, {
    success: function(result) {
        console.log("Successfully invited user!");
        console.log("Please have your patient log in with the following code: " + doctorCode);
        },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("There has been an error.");
        console.log(error);
        }
    });
createpatientwindow.style.visibility = "hidden";
$(generatecalorieswindow).addClass("slideLeft");

};
```

For some reason, I'm not even getting the first console message from the javascript function. Am I hooking up the jQuery listener wrong?

Comment: _And I'm using this jQuery listener in my CSS stylesheet:_ <<< really, in your stylesheet?

Comment: That's how I learned (very recently learned) to put it. Is there a more efficient/standard location?

Comment: I have moved my jquery listeners, but the code still does not execute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your function inside lambda, like this:

```
$('#patientcreatebutton').click(function() {
  createpatient($('#form1'));
});
```

Comment: are you sure you initialized the click() handler inside document ready function?

Comment: Oh. I don't think I did that. I'm mostly learning as I make it. How would initializing the handler look?

Comment: You need to have $(document).ready() somewhere in your code and execute all javascript inside it.

$(document).ready(function() {
    //all your javascript code goes here.
});